# Audit state-change in MySQL

Tags: mysql, plugins, audit

Assume a number of conventional LAMP-style applications which use MySQL as a back-end to record the 'current durable state' for the applications.

I am interested in establishing an 'audit' of transitions at the database level - and storing them as a log.  The idea is that - assuming the MySQL database has been 'dumped' at the beginning of the day, it would be possible to 'replay' transactions against the back-up to recover any state during the working day....  A bit like time-machine for MySQL - I guess.

I have found some documentation about "Audit plugins" which look relevant but leaves me with more questions than answers.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/writing-audit-plugins.html

Essentially, I'd like to establish if it would be feasible to write a MySQL plugin to achieve my goal - such that it would work 'seamlessly' with existing MySQL applications?

The principal detail I'm finding it difficult to ascertain is this:  When the audit-plugin is notified of an event, what is the mechanism by which the new data can be established in order to log it?  How are data types encoded? How hard would it be to write a tool to 'replay' this audit against a 'full-system-backup' using mysqldump, for example?

Are there any existing examples of such plugins?

Answer (score 0):

You just want MySQL's [Point-in-Time (Incremental) Recovery Using the Binary Log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/point-in-time-recovery.html):

> Point-in-time recovery refers to recovery of data changes made since a given point in time. Typically, this type of recovery is performed after restoring a full backup that brings the server to its state as of the time the backup was made. (The full backup can be made in several ways, such as those listed in [Section 7.2, “Database Backup Methods”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/backup-methods.html).) Point-in-time recovery then brings the server up to date incrementally from the time of the full backup to a more recent time

Comment: Binary logs definitely look relevant... However... I was hoping to do something bespoke with each "transaction's data"... rather than just write it into a file.  Do these 'binary logs' have a documented format?  Is there a way to hook the event that a new transaction has been recorded in the binary log?

Comment: In addition to knowing the time and being able to see the SQL statements, I'd like to be able to record high-level labels originating from the applications... e.g. "Delete contact" - rather than have to reverse engineer that from the SQL.

Comment: @aSteve: There are tools (such as [mysqlbinlog](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysqlbinlog.html)) that can parse the binary log for you and extract data that may be of interest.  If you want to parse it yourself, the full format is [documented in the Internals Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/binary-log.html).  Being selective about which transactions you replay sounds pretty scary to me, but even then I'm sure there are existing tools out there which can assist and prevent you from having to roll your own (with all the pitfalls that would entail).

Comment: The "internals manual" looks very helpful... especially if, as I now suspect, I can audit these binary logging events.  I'm not inclined towards the SP approach as it would require extensive changes to legacy code... though I recognise it as a potential approach for new systems. My aim is to minimize the audit data, while maximising its contextual labels, while minimising changes to existing systems.  I recognise that this wouldn't be a trivial project. :)

Comment: Oh, and before you worry... Yes, missing out some step in the binary log would be very risky... but, I can stop at any point... and roll-back to that point in history... or, alternatively, export data at any point in the history from the application itself.  The challenge is in identifying which historic version of the database to export from.

Comment: @aSteve: I'm just not sure that I understand why you can't build your recovery tool around [Point-in-Time Recovery Using Event Positions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/point-in-time-recovery-positions.html)... it sounds like the only missing part is identifying the event IDs that you (don't) wish to replay?

Comment: Identification of the 'point-in-time' is one of the main challenges - the other is that I don't want to rely upon the local file-system to store the audit... because that gives a single point of failure.

Comment: @aSteve: Protecting against storage failure is another matter entirely -- one can use RAID, network-mounted filesystems, file synchronisation tools, etc etc -- and both off-topic for SO and out of the scope of this question.  The article to which my last comment linked suggests one way that one might identify "point-in-time"; together with a separate log of timestamp + high level actions, you ought to pretty much be there?

Comment: I agree - the relative merits of RAID/NFS/File-sync are off-topic here... especially as I already have a suitable bespoke 'service' in mind.  Your pointer to the internals manual was key, I think... very helpful with respect to estimating the scope of a proposed integration effort.  The other odd-ball idea would be to write custom storage engine as a veneer over the standard one...